# Using google map API to open *.map or other map file ( offline map )

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3, offline

Is it possible to open map file at local computer (offline) using google map API? If yes, How?
I have programed an application in delphi. It shows the company cars on the map. but now we need the map to be offline. I have *.map file and may be I can find other map file from internet. I have not a point where to start at all. What do I have to do? tnx.

Comment: Google maps API interact with google servers, online. There is no way to use maps API's. If its a web interface you can try looking at HTML5 projects which have ported maps offline with co-ordinate resolution.

Comment: @Shouvik Add that as the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to show a map offline using javascript or delphi? I only want to show some markers on map. Can you please provide me a link or website? I do not have any expriance with offline maps. really thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google maps works by transferring data asynchronously from Google's servers to a user's computer.  So if you are offline there's no way to communicate with Google's servers and retrieve such info. Even if you accomplish store the cached google maps and display offline you must follow the [Google Maps API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i)
>   limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily,
>   securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content
>   outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that
>   the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For
>   example, you must not use the Content to create an independent
>   database of "places" or other local listings information.

As alternative you can use the [`Google Static Maps API V2`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) service you can retrieve a image, which can be saved to a file, basically you need build a URI like so

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false

And the using a GET you save the response in a file, check this article for a delphi sample [`Using Google maps (Static Maps) without TWebBrowser`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/using-google-maps-static-maps-without-twebbrowser/)

Comment: No I don't think the offline caching of the static images are allowed either. Please check link I provided in my answer.

Comment: I ahte it when that happens without justification too. But i think its mostly because offline caching of maps is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

Google maps API interact with google servers, online. There is no way to use maps API's. If its a web interface you can try looking at HTML5 projects which have ported maps offline with co-ordinate resolution.

[Here is your FAQ related to storing google maps data offline](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_staticmaps_reuse)

What I suggested about HTML5 projects, you can take a look at [this](http://www.webglearth.org/).
This combined with offline html5 offline data caching should be a good solution for your problem.